# Holographic lighting in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, light

Is it possible to create a holographic lighting in cycles? This is possible In the Blender Internal render engine, but I'm not going for linking lamps. Here is what I mean (the light that is holding the sphere inside it) -

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using volumetrics:

[image]

## Method 1:

Using a cube to scatter light emitted from a spot lamp.

1. Create a cube and give it a volume scatter material:

   [image]
2. Add a spot lamp:

   [image]

## Method 2:

You could also fake this by modeling the cone, then using a volumetric gradient for the falloff:

[image]

It won't be as physically accurate or as flexible, but it will be less noisy:

[image]

---

[**Example .blend**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31643) (for both methods)

Comment: Thanks. is the light source a "sun lamp"?

Comment: @Vladimir No, a sun lamp wouldn't work for this at all..

Comment: Would you like to post a blend? 'Cause the volume is showing the shape of the cube and its nothing like your image above.