# Show cone for spotlight is not showing up after the scene is rendered

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

The first image is the scene in the render it shows the spotlight with cone, but i render the same scene the cone for the spotlight is not showing up. Don't know why!

P.S.(I removed the building at the bottom from rendered image)

[image: Screenshot of the scene in blender] 
[image: Image after rendering]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't make your questions a guessing game, put some effort into your post. Describe thoroughly what you did and how, what you expect to happen and where it failed. Right now all we know is a purple grape in a black background

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos sorry I posted initially in a rush and couldn't put up the issue in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Show cone" is just a viewport helper.

Guess you meant a light in volume, look at  [Volumetric Spot Light with Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38830/volumetric-spot-light-with-cycles)

For eevee https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daCTRzzmpyk